# Can someone explain why there is a discontinuity in beam's Shear Force Diagram with a third support?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics, structural-beam

Here is an example:
[image: result]
https://beamguru.com/online/beam-calculator/?save=02461c5130daee73a8c73a51060e2adc

The reaction forces are $R_a$ and $R_b$.

But when it comes to the Shear Force diagram after the initial $817.50$ and $12m$ I dont understand this becomes $-4222.50 \ kN$

Comment: still dont understand their output for Q2(30) =  + 817.50 - ([(350 - 350*(57 - 30)/45)*(30 - 12)]/2 + 350*(57 - 30)/45*(30 - 12)) = -4222.50 (kN)

Answer (score 2):

From the solution shear diagram jump, it is obvious that $R_B = 2835 - (-4222) = 7057$ and that is what the solver shows in the output:

[image]

The value of $-4222$ has to equal $R_A$ minus the area under the load up to *B* (indicated blue below)

[image]

So check your math.

Comment: yeah but why  do we need to go thru all that what is the logic behind it, I know it checks out but I am interested in why it is so, why does it go  ([(350 - 350*(57 - 30)/45)*(30 - 12)]/2 + 350*(57 - 30)/45*(30 - 12))

Comment: Because to reach equilibrium the total weight (blue area) must be counter-acted by the supports. Each support causes a jump in the shear diagram equal to the support force value. I really do not understand what you are asking here. You seem to understand how statics works, yet you are confused by the shear diagram.

Comment: how do I get the area if it is not an even distirubted load all I have is 18m and 350kN/m

Comment: @stormy2020 - use the geometry you learned in high school. Subtract the area of the triangle to the right of _B_ from the big triangle to get the area of the trapezoid.

Comment: big one 1/2*45*350=7875  small one B right  1/2*27*350=4725  B left 3150...

Answer (score 1):

You already know the numbers add up, so I don't need to explain the magnitude of the jump.

The reason for the "jump" is that the shearing force within a beam is undefined at the point of the application of a concentrated force, whether that force be a concentrated load or a reaction force at a support.

So the "jump" in the shear diagram simply means shear is not defined at the reaction B. It is only defined to the left and right of the reaction force.

Furthermore the reason the shear force (and related shear stress) is undefined at concentrated forces (forces applied to a point)  is because in reality such forces don’t exist. If they did they would would create infinite stress. All real macroscopic forces are applied over some area.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that the first force acting is Fay which is 817.50 and that it stays the same for that 12m, I also now that the distributed load will cause a fall til it meets Fby which will go up 7075.50 but I am lost at how did they get to the huge process with which they got the -4222.50 whose diffrence of Fby leads to 2835, and I know it needs to end in zero for the balance

Comment: @stirmy2020 I’ve added an explanation for why the shear force is undefined